# Accessing slice of 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, slice

I have a 3D numpy array of floating point numbers. Am I indexing the array improperly? I'd like to access slice 124 (index 123) but am seeing this error:

```
>>> arr.shape
(31, 285, 286)
>>> arr[:][123][:]
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 123 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 31
```

What would be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`arr[:][123][:]` is processed piece by piece, not as a whole.

```
arr[:]  # just a copy of `arr`; it is still 3d
arr[123]  # select the 123 item along the first dimension
# oops, 1st dim is only 31, hence the error.
```

`arr[:, 123, :]` is processed as whole expression.  Select one 'item' along the middle axis, and return everything along the other two.

`arr[12][123]` would work, because that first select one 2d array from the 1st axis.  Now `[123]` works on that `285` length dimension, returning a 1d array.  Repeated indexing `[][]..` works just often enough to confuse new programmrs, but usually it is not the right expression.

Comment: thanks! and thanks for the clarification on arr[:] being an initial copy of arr. I often forget that.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might just want to do `arr[:,123,:]`.  That gives you a 2D array with a shape of (31, 286), with the contents of the 124th place along that axis.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
arr.flatten()[123]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this returns a single value, not a slice.

Answer (score 0):

Look up at some slice examples of a xD array. You can try this:

`a[:,123,:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

s=np.ones((31,285,286)) # 3D array of size 3x3 with "one" values
s[:,123,:] # access index 123 as you want
```